# PMD - How to exclude files from violation check

Tags: maven, pmd

We're checking our code using the PMD 'check' goal that is bound to the 'verify' life cycle. (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/violationChecking.html)

For the 'pmd' goal you can add 'excludes' and 'excludeRoots' but not for the 'check' goal.

How does one exclude eg. generated sources directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the pmd:pmd first and afterwards do a pmd:check. You can [configure](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/violationChecking.html) that simply by using. Bind that to a particular lifecycle-phase which is before verify. For example into package or pre-integration-test phase.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>pmd</goal>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The check goals (check, cpd-check are exactly intended to fail a build if there are some violations. So you can define some exceptions for the pmd goal which folders should be included/excluded.